# Distributed Software Architecture - Communication Paging

Tags: .net, wcf, memory, memory-management, communication

Actually I don't know if SO is right place to ask, but I don't know another place with so many professional developers.

I heard, when developing distributed applications, it's important to implement "communication paging" for large objects in order to allow to .NET to manage memory more efficiently, because .NET first clears small (~80KB) objects from memory and large objects (>~80KB) leaves in memory more time.

What I mean...let's say I have client object called "Context" and server object called "Provider". The communication between client and server implemented using WCF TCP binding and binary serialization. Now, Context makes request to Server to retrieve the list of complex objects. The memory size of that list is ~300KB or more, and potentially the server can get many requests per second for different instances of that list. So because of what I heard, it means, that I need to split the request for (X / 80KB) requests, in order to work with small (~80KB) objects.

In practice, the CTO of the company where I work, want me to implement the logic of that communication paging in Context and Provider. Means, create loop in Context that make X request to Provider with information about already received data and create logic in Provider that will send the list in chunks.

For me it sounds very strange...since anyway the large object already in memory on server, and making more requests uses more CPU, Network and additional memory to manage all that communication.

Can someone explain me how to handle that interesting case or where I can read about transferring large objects in WCF?

Thanks